# In the angularjs-ui-tree, Initial rendering takes time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs-ui-tree,

Replacing the data with a large amount of data took time to render.

▼ sample source

http://embed.plnkr.co/bKJNoG/

Replacing the data with a lot of data, displaying the screen took time to render.

At the initial display of the screen, loading images are displayed, and after rendering we are thinking of hiding the loading image,
How should we implement event callback after rendering is over?

Thank you for your interest

Postscript

If you know

In the case of ie11, display processing is considerably slow, and the loading image also becomes hardened.
I would be pleased if you could tell me if there is any workaround.

Comment: Can you please give steps, how how it will work? like click on expand icon it will show loader and then hide load ?